# Svelte component as target of a11y-label-has-associated-control rule

Tags: accessibility, svelte

I created a Svelte component `<MyInput>` that outputs `<input>`.

```html
<label>
  Some text
  <MyInput />
</label>
```

Then the [`svelte-check`](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/tree/master/packages/svelte-check#readme) warns this error:

> A11y: A form label must be associated with a control. svelte (a11y-label-has-associated-control)

I found the similar rule [`jsx-a11y/label-has-associated-control`](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/main/docs/rules/label-has-associated-control.md), and thought the `controlComponents` options would solve it, but Svelte does not refer ESLint config. (Right, it's JSX anyway.)

How to tell Svelte that the component is the associated control?

Quick fixes I found but don't want

- Add a random `for` like `<label for="nothing">` (obviously a bad idea)
- Embed `<label>` inside the `<MyInput>` as well as label text (but I wish not-complex component here)

Comment: svelte-check is wrong. Having an `<input>` nested inside a `<label>` **is** a valid way to associate a label with an input field and that passes accessibility and WCAG.  You *could* add an ID to the `<input>` and specify that ID in the `for` attribute of the `<label>`, as you alluded to, but the ID wouldn't be for "nothing". But the only reason to do that would be to pass the svelte-check checker, which is not really a valid reason for doing so.

Comment: If you want a reference, see the [`<label>` spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), in particular, *"If the `for` attribute is **not** specified, **but the label element has a labelable element descendant**, then the first such descendant in tree order is the label element's labeled control."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a false positive. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/6469) regarding that.

You can only really ignore the warning right now:

```html
<!-- svelte-ignore a11y-label-has-associated-control -->
<label>...
```

To only have the ignore in one place you could create a `Label` component, though that of course creates some unnecessary component overhead.